# Finding first index of first ocurrence of digits

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector of digits:

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5]
```

I want to find the index of the first occurrence of either a 2, 3 or 5. So in this case, the index will be 8.

I have thought of converting the 1s to 0s and then finding the first occurrence of a non-zero but that seems inefficient. Is there any efficient way of doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5];
find(x==2 | x==3 | x==5, 1)
```

Comment: To make it more general you could use `v = [2 3 5]; find(ismember(x,v),1)`

Comment: @LuisMendo that should have been an answer!

Comment: @Tyler consider using the second output of `max`. I think it'll be computationally more efficient.